# How to write mockito for annotated parameter in function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, springmockito

I am new to mockito testing. I am trying to learn and could not find answer for my specific problem.

I have method as below in one of the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = /employer, method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
public HttpStatus saveEmployerInfo (@Valid @RequestBody EmployerInfo empInfo,
                               HttpServletRequest request)
{
        String employeeId = (String) request.getAttribute(EMP_ATTRIBUTE);
        employerService.processEmpInfo(empInfo, employeeId);
        return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

I am trying to do below in mockito:

```
EmployerInfo mockEmpInfo = mock(EmployerInfo.class);
HttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
Controller mockController = mock(Controller.class);
when(mockController.saveEmployerInfo(Matchers.any(EmployerInfo.class), (HttpServletRequest) any(HttpServletRequest.class))).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
HttpStatus responseStatus = mockController.saveEmployerInfo(Matchers.any(EmployerInfo.class),
  (HttpServletReq(mockEmpInfo, mockHttpServletRequest);
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseStatus.OK);
```

I am still getting below errors and not able to solve this issue :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf cannot be cast to com.xxx.model.EmployerInfo
```

Comment: Your test does not make much sense: 1. There seems to be a missing `)`  on the call to saveEmployerInfo, 2. everything is mocked, so calling your method you want to test on a mocked instance is bound to give you and error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your controller, you have to do it on a real instance and not a mocked instance. Assuming your controller looks something like this:

```
@Controller
public class EmployerController {
  @Autowire
  EmployerService employerService;

  @RequestMapping(value = /employer, method = RequestMethod.POST,
                  consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
  public HttpStatus saveEmployerInfo (@Valid @RequestBody EmployerInfo empInfo,
                               HttpServletRequest request) {
        String employeeId = (String) request.getAttribute(EMP_ATTRIBUTE);
        employerService.processEmpInfo(empInfo, employeeId);
        return HttpStatus.OK;
  }
}
```

Then the test could look like this (with Juni4):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployerControllerTest {

  @Mock
  private EmployerService employerService;

  @InjectMocks
  private EmployerController controller;

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnHttpStatusOk() {
    // Given
    EmployerInfo mockEmpInfo = mock(EmployerInfo.class);
    HttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    String employerId = "employerId"
    when(mockHttpServletRequest.getAttribute(EMP_ATTRIBUTE)).willReturn(employerId);

    // When
    HttpStatus status = controller.saveEmployerInfo(mockEmpInfo, mockHttpServletRequest);

    // Then
    verify(employerService).processEmpInfo(mockEmpInfo, employerId); 
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, status);
  }  
}
```